# Creating SandBox account buttons

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I have created a SandBox account with -facilitator and -buyer test accounts, and logged in as the -facilitator account to create a test Buy Now button. I originally did this using a live PayPal account and it worked fine, although I never went through to the end and actuall bought anything.

My concern is that having logged into the SandBox account (`www.sandbox.paypal.com` is in the address) when I create a Buy Now button, the code is shown on a page with www.paypal.com in the address bar and the button code includes form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" `method="post"`..

In the PayPal documentation, it shows a code snippet with form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" `method="post"`..

Note that the URL with my button is not for the SandBox, whereas the documentation URL is. I am doing this from the UK but it seems wrong to me. I have not tested it but was hoping someone could comment?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about your problem.

If the form action points toward "https://www.paypal.com....." this means that the payment is made in the Live environment of PayPal.

In order to have a button pointing to Sandbox, the form action will have to begin with "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com....."

For example, this is a button pointing toward sandbox environment

```html
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Object name">
 <input type="hidden" name="business"value="youremail@email.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="47.47">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
 <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_buynow_cc_171x47.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
 <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
<form>
```

Hoping my answer will help you.

Comment: Thank's for that. What cause my eye was that there were things like input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6RNT8A4HBBJRE" in the example code and I wasn't sure if this value would cause a problem if I just changed the form action code as you suggest. However, only one way to find out!

Comment: Looking at the generated code, the only thing which identifies the account is the hosted_button_id and it's value and I have tried simply changing the form action URL from www.paypal.com to www.sandbox.paypal.com but it doesn't work. My guess would be that there is an error in the PayPal system that takes me to the main site to generate the code rather than the SandBox site and that when I use the code, it cannot find the value id. I will keep trying but I may just use the live system and sacrifice some pennies in commission!

Comment: The hosted buttons are generated by PayPal following a configuration you do in paypal.com or sandbox.paypal.com. you cannot interchange the environment just by changing the endpoint of the hosted button. Indeed, the hosted_button_id refer to a button configuration store in either sandbox env or paypal env and if you want to migrate a hosted button from sandbox to Paypal, you will have to re-do it manually on https://www.paypal.com/fr/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-management